# Reducing a string from a file, into a new file

Tags: python

I want to make python make a new file from the file I already have, then reduce the letters from the first file and in the new file.

This is what i got so far, without any luck:

```
my_file = open("my_full.txt", "r")
my_file2 = open("my_partial.txt", "w")

for each_line in my_file:
    my_file2.write(len[0:2]+"\n")

my_file.close()
my_file2.close()
```

Example:
"This must be reduced"
"This is one as well"
"And the last one"
I now want python to open up the first one, and reduce the letters in the first file and make a new one, with the result.

so the new file python makes should contain for example:
"Thi"
"Thi"
"And"

Comment: When you say reduce, you mean just take the first 3 letters from each line?

Comment: Yes @PaulRooney , and putting the 3 letters in another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it!

Inside of your `for` loop, you need to change the `write` call to:

```
my_file2.write(each_line[:3] + '\n')
```

There are two problems with the line you currently have:

1. You're using `len` instead of the variable holding the current line of the file which is a function in python to determine the length of a given item (e.g. string, list, etc.)
2. You want the first `3` characters but are using the range of `[0:2]` which is ending exclusive so you will only get the first `2`. That must be changed to `[0:3]`.

Comment: Thank you so much! this helped! Oh, i totally forgot the 0:3 part , wops!

Comment: only very pedantic corner case would be if the line was less than 3 characters and the newline was included in the slice, then you append a second newline. Not a major consideration and I'm sure the OP doesn't care about that.